# Highchart: Internal Server error NOW

Tags: svg, highcharts

I have an issue today with highchart as their export server is sending me **Internal Server Error** and my call is fall into error. So I checked with their export.highcharts.com & select option SVG and then try to see the preview and I got **Internal Server Error** same error at the moment so can anyone know how it going to resolved?

& my second question is can anyone provide me an link which going to show me step through regarding how to build your own export server?

Please it's not same question thank you in advance.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was temporary problem with our exporting server, but now all should work properly.

You can also setup your own exporting server.

Manual: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server